# adapter.notifyDataSetChange() not working after called from onResume()

Tags: android, android-adapter

I am having a problem where when I call the `adapter.notifyDataSetChange()` to refresh the listActifity from the `onResume()` function, it doesn't seem to be working from any other functions from that activity afterwards.

I want the list(view) to refresh when the user clicks the back button(while on another screen) and returns to the window with the list. 
One of the things I noticed is that the `notifyDataSetChange()` works(from other functions) when I change one of the objects from the array list but not when I want to add or delete an object from the `ArrayList`. This has been working so far for me, but I would prefer not to have to requery the list every time.

```
@Override  
        protected void onResume() {  
        lightWeightDAO.open(); //db connection  
        adapter.clear();  
        buckets = lightWeightDAO.getExerciseBucketsByWorkoutId(workout.getId());   
        adapter.addAll(buckets);  
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
        super.onResume();      
    }
```

When I remove the notifyDataSetChange() from the onResume(), everything seems to work(just calling a simple notifyDataSetChange() after changing the arraylist).

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: use "{}" button for code

Comment: As a note most adapters' `add()`, `addAll()`, etc methods call `notifyDataSetChanged()` for you. What data types are `adapter` and `buckets`?

Comment: adapter is an ExerciseBucketArrayAdapter that extends ArrayAdapter<ExerciseBucket>, buckets is an ArrayList<ExerciseBucket> where ExerciseBucket is just a serialiazable data class with getters and setters. Hope this helps.

Comment: Call super.onResume() as first method in your overriden onResume

Comment: How do you add data in the other functions: `buckets.add()` or `adapter.add()`? (To reply to a specific user use `@Sam` otherwise I might not notice you replied.)

Comment: @Sam I use 'buckets.add()' to add the buckets to the 'ArrayList()'.

Comment: @Herr K placing 'super.onResume()' before the code did not change  the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using:

```
buckets = lightWeightDAO.getExerciseBucketsByWorkoutId(workout.getId());   
adapter.addAll(buckets);
```

You have only *added* the contents of this new `buckets` to the adapter, you didn't *bind* the adapter to `buckets`. So this:

```
buckets.add(string);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

has no affect on the data inside the adapter. Also like I mentioned above in the comments, you can add to the adapter directly and it will call `notifyDataSetChanged()` for you. So simply replace everywhere you use the two lines above with:

```
adapter.add(string);
```